# NavGraph.addAll() to add nested nav graph progamatically not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to have two versions of `nav_graph` in two build variant so and the first variant will use the `main` `nav_graph` and the second variant will add some more destinations to the main `nav_graph` so this makes the second graph duplicate of the main `nav_graph` but with more destinations which is hard to manage and keep update both at the same time so to solve this i go for dynamic navigation by creating a navigation graph by code which works fine but when i want to add a nested graph for second build variant destinations to the `MainGraph` it's not working

this file is in the main code base

**MainGraph**

```
object MainGraph{

    var id_counter = 1

    private val id = id_counter++

    object Destinations {
        val mainFragment = id_counter++
        // ...
    }

    object Actions {
        // ...
        val to_settingsFragment = id_counter++
    }

    fun setGraph(context: Context, navController: NavController) {

        navController.graph = navController.createGraph(id, Destinations.mainFragment) {

            fragment<MainFragment>(Destinations.mainFragment) {
                label = context.getString(R.string.app_name)

                // ...

                action(Actions.to_settingsFragment) {
                    destinationId = Destinations.settingsFragment
                }
            }

            // ...

            fragment<SettingsFragment>(Destinations.settingsFragment) {
                label = context.getString(R.string.settings)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this file only in the second build variant

**NestedGraph**

```
object NestedGraph {

    val id = MainGraph.id_counter++

    object Destinations {
        val nestedFirstFragment = MainGraph.id_counter++
        val nestedSecondFragment = MainGraph.id_counter++
    }

    object Actions {
        val to_nestedSecondFragment = MainGraph.id_counter++
    }

    fun addDestinations(navController: NavController) {

        val navGraph = navController.createGraph(
            this@NestedGraph.id,
            Destinations.nestedFirstFragment
        ) {

            fragment<NestedFirstFragment>(Destinations.nestedFirstFragment) {
                action(Actions.to_nestedSecondFragment) {
                    destinationId = Destinations.nestedSecondFragment 
                }
            }

            fragment<NestedSecondFragment>(Destinations.nestedSecondFragment)
        }

        navController.graph.addAll(navGraph) // not working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging and try n fail i found that there is not wrong with NavGraph.addAll() method its working find it's just my mistake i was using the nested graph id instead of destination id when calling `navigate` and if anyone in future also get this kind of behaviour just make sure make the `id` variable private